# InterpolationOrder 2 or more in ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I'm using the function `ListLogLinearPlot`, but the plot is to square, i would like to have `InterpolationOrder` 2, but there is not this command for the function.

I tried to make my own interpolation, creating a function which create more points between my pre-existing points:

```
Int1[p0_, n0_] := 
 Module[{p = p0, n = n0, i, j, a, b, l = {}, x, y},
  Table[
   a = (p[[i + 1, 1]] - p[[i, 1]])/(n + 1);
   b = (p[[i + 1, 2]] - p[[i, 2]])/(n + 1);
   Table[
    x = p[[i, 1]] + a*j;
    y = p[[i, 2]] + b*j;
    AppendTo[l, {x, y}];
    , {j, 0, n}
    ]
   , {i, 1, Length[p] - 1}
   ];
  AppendTo[l, p[[-1]]];
  l
  ]
nn = 3;
Int1[Points, nn];
```

But, i can't make it works

@MarcoB

```
PSt = {RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.8], 
  Thickness[0.005]}; PSa = {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], Thickness[0.003]};
PSb = {RGBColor[0.3, 0.3, 0.3], 
  Thickness[0.002]}; PSc = {RGBColor[0.3, 0.3, 0.3], Thickness[0.001]};

FinosCA = {{0, 0}, {0.15, 2}, {0.3, 10}, {0.6, 25}, {1.18, 50}, {2.36,
     80}, {4.75, 95}, {9.5, 100}};
FinosCB = {{0, 0}, {0.15, 10}, {0.3, 30}, {0.6, 60}, {1.18, 
    85}, {2.36, 100}, {4.75, 100}, {9.5, 100}};
FinosCC = {{0, 0}, {0.15, 10}, {0.3, 50}, {0.6, 95}, {1.18, 
    100}, {2.36, 100}, {4.75, 100}, {9.5, 100}};
FinosCM = {{0, 0.34}, {0.15, 2.6}, {0.3, 26.68}, {0.6, 96.60}, {1.18, 
    99.64}, {2.36, 99.94}, {4.75, 100}, {9.5, 100}};
nn = 50
ListLogLinearPlot[{FinosCA, FinosCB, FinosCC, FinosCM}, 
 Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Diamentro de malla\ndel tamiz [mm]", 
   "% Pasante Acumulado"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14], 
 ImageSize -> 650, PlotStyle -> {PSa, PSb, PSc, PSt}]
ListLogLinearPlot[{Int1[FinosCA, nn], Int1[FinosCB, nn], 
  Int1[FinosCC, nn], Int1[FinosCM, nn]}, Joined -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Diamentro de malla\ndel tamiz [mm]", 
   "% Pasante Acumulado"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14], 
 ImageSize -> 650, PlotStyle -> {PSa, PSb, PSc, PSt}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you include your existing points, the code you have used so far, and maybe an example of output?

Comment: @MarcoB I changed the post

Comment: Gonzalo, thanks for the update. Could you expand a little on what exactly you would like to accomplish as well? I'm afraid that I did not completely understand what you need to do. Do you want a "smoother" plot? Or do you want perhaps a fit function?

Comment: @MarcoB i want... a curve line instead of a rect-poliline

Comment: @MarcoB yes, i want a "smoother" plot

Answer (score 3):

You can get a smoother result by taking the `Log` before making the interpolation:

```
loginterp[x_] = 
  Interpolation[{Log10[#1], #2} & @@@ Rest@#, InterpolationOrder -> 2][Log10[x]] & /@ 
    {FinosCA, FinosCB, FinosCC, FinosCM};

Show[
  LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@loginterp[x], {x, FinosCA[[2, 1]], FinosCA[[-1, 1]]}], 
  ListLogLinearPlot[{FinosCA, FinosCB, FinosCC, FinosCM}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without taking the `Log` first, you'll get more spurious wiggles, even when using the `"Spline"` method:

```
interp[x_] = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"][x] & /@ 
  {FinosCA, FinosCB, FinosCC, FinosCM};

Show[
  LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@interp[x], {x, FinosCA[[2, 1]], FinosCA[[-1, 1]]}], 
  ListLogLinearPlot[{FinosCA, FinosCB, FinosCC, FinosCM}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

You can add the options `InterpolationOrder -> 2` and `PlotRange -> {0.1, 110}` to your `ListLogLinearPlot`. As all your data points start at 0, you have to remove these using `Rest`.

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{Rest@FinosCA, Rest@FinosCB, Rest@FinosCC, Rest@FinosCM}, 
 Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Diamentro de malla\ndel tamiz [mm]", "% Pasante Acumulado"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14], ImageSize -> 650, 
 PlotStyle -> {PSa, PSb, PSc, PSt}, InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotRange -> {0.1, 110}]
```

> [image: Out]

Answer (score 2):

I propose to use the build-in interpolating function `Interpolation` which is a continuous function, and then to make sampling at higher frequency :

```
FinosCA = {{0, 0}, {0.15, 2}, {0.3, 10}, {0.6, 25}, {1.18, 50}, {2.36,
      80}, {4.75, 95}, {9.5, 100}};;

interpolatingFunction = Interpolation[FinosCA, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

n = 10; (* number of new points betwen initial points *)
newPointsAbcissa = 
  Flatten[Range[#[[1]], #[[2]], (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/(n + 1)] & /@ 
    Partition[First /@ FinosCA, 2, 1]];

Show[
 ListLogLinearPlot[
   Table[
        {x, interpolatingFunction[x]},
        {x,newPointsAbcissa}
        ]],
 ListLogLinearPlot[FinosCA, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[FinosCA]}]
 ]
```

[image]

In red : the initial points.

**EDIT**

Of course, if you don't need the intermediate points, you can plot directly the continuous interpolating function. Here is the code :

```
{xmin, xmax} = {Min[#], Max[#]} & @ (First /@ Rest[FinosCA])
LogLinearPlot[interpolatingFunction[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

Note : I have removed the first point of `FinosCA` (see code `Rest[FinosCA]` above) which is {0,0} and is -Infinity on a Log scale.

**EDIT**

The cusp is removed if you use the option `Method -> "Spline"` :

```
interpolatingFunction = 
  Interpolation[FinosCA, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"];
```

[image]

Comment: Once you have `interpolatingFunction` why not directly call `LogLinearPlot`?

Comment: @Rahul : you could, of course, but I think that this presentation is more in the spirit of the question : one can see here how to re-sample (one say up-sample ?) irregular data.

Comment: @Rahul I have added the `LogLinearPlot` solution